# Как сделать insert специальных знаков в postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Как можно в postgresql внести данные, которые как массив, типо '["abc", "abc"]'. В основном ругается из-за этого знака, но мне не нужно его хранить, как text[] или varchar[], а именно в обычном text или varchar с этим знаком "[]"
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "[")

Comment: запрос с данными покажите. `create temp table a (v text); insert into a values ('["abc", "abc"]');` - никаких проблем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [4.1.2.4. Строковые константы, заключённые в доллары](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-syntax-lexical#sql-syntax-dollar-quoting)

```
INSERT INTO myseq(my_data) VALUES($$'["abc", "abc"]'$$);
```

Это упростит [задачу](https://dbfiddle.uk/b2jpzkJO).